# "Subscript out of range" error when calling LBound() or UBound() on a VBA array

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following code produces the error "Subscript out of range" and I do not know why. Can someone please explain?

```
    Dim errorc As Integer
    Dim myarray() As Variant


    errorc = 1

    If Len(Me.txt_Listnum) = 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve myarray(errorc)
    myarray(errorc) = "Numer Listy"
    errorc = errorc + 1
    End If

    If Len(Me.cbo_ByWho) = 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve myarray(errorc)
    myarray(errorc) = "Wystawione przez"
    errorc = errorc + 1
    End If

    If Len(Me.cbo_ForWho) = 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve myarray(errorc)
    myarray(errorc) = "Wystawione na"
    errorc = errorc + 1
    End If

    For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
        msg = msg & myarray(i) & vbNewLine
    Next i

    If errorc > 0 Then
       MsgBox "da" & msg

    End If
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code will fail if all of the form controls are populated and therefore `myarray` never gets `ReDim`'d. For an unititialized dynamic array,

```
Dim myarray() As Variant
```

(i.e., one that has not been subsequently sized with `ReDim`), calling `LBound()` or `UBound()` on it will fail with "Subscript out of range."

Comment: @user3002600 Put the `For` loop inside the `If errorc ...` block and check for `errorc > 1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

My VB(A) is far away, but still. the `(Re)Dim()` method defines the size of the array; the index of the array goes from 0 to size-1. Therefore, when you do this :

```
errorc = 1

If Len(Me.txt_Listnum) = 0 Then
ReDim Preserve myarray(errorc)
myarray(errorc) = "Numer Listy"
errorc = errorc + 1
End If
```

1. You redimension myarray to contain 1 element (`ReDim Preserve myarray(errorc)`). it will have only 1 index : 0
2. you try to place something in index 1 (`myarray(errorc) = "Numer Listy"`), which will fail with the error message you mention.

So what you should to is organize things like this :

```
errorc = 0

If Len(Me.txt_Listnum) = 0 Then
    errorc = errorc + 1 'if we get here, there's 1 error more
    ReDim Preserve myarray(errorc) 'extend the array to the number of errors
    myarray(errorc-1) = "Numer Listy" 'place the error message in the last index of the array, which you could get using UBound() too
End If
```

EDIT

Following your remark, I had a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/95b8f22f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I'm a bit surprised. From where I see it UBound should return the size of the array -1, but from the examples given it seems it returns the size of the array, point. So, if the examples on that page are correct (and your error seems to indicate they are), you should write your loop this way :

```
For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)-1
    msg = msg & myarray(i) & vbNewLine
Next i
```

Comment: Somehow the error occurs 
For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    msg = msg & myarray(i) & vbNewLine
Next i ||||| subscript out of range

Comment: Have you even tried debugging ? does it always fail or only when you've got no errors ? Just check the values of i and the size of you're array. It's almost sure you're trying to access an index which doesn't exist in your array. It could happen when your array is empty, for example... Sorry but it's been too long since I've done any VB for me to be more affirmative on this :-)

Comment: the array isnt empty for sure:P I don't know.. is there a other way to make a msg box with empty txt/combo fields?